# Need to come up with an equation or method to calculate a ratio between two arrays of numbers

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance

I have two arrays of data:

| # of Files | Time to Process in seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 4 | 76 |

What I'm wanting to do is come up with an estimate of how long it will take to process n number of files. I have processed 1-4 files and have noted the time it takes in seconds to process n number of files. I guess I'm trying to figure out a usable equation or ratio that will produce results close to what I have in the table above. I'm not sure if I should use variance, co-variance, correlation or some other statistical method to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are these data independent or cumulative?  That is, do they reflect timings for $1+2+3+4=10$ different files or for total times observed to process $1,$ then $2,$ then $3,$ and then $4$ files (so you observed the times for only $4$ distinct files)?

Comment: Correct, I observed times for only 4 files. I thought it would be enough to extrapolate some means of figuring out a way to predict the time

Comment: The discipline of extrapolating a series of regular events is called *Time Series Analysis.*  It's a big subject.  How to approach it depends on the particulars of your problem.  The simplest solution is when you can be sure the successive times (8, 20-8 =12, 31-20=11, and 76-31=46 seconds) are statistically independent, for then you have a *sample* with values 8, 12, 11, and 46 and you wish to predict how many seconds $n$ files will require.  That can be done by computing a [prediction interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+interval%22), *q.v.*

Comment: Strange that the last (fourth) file took so much longer than the first three, actually more than the first three together. I doubt that you get a very precise prediction out of such a small sample.